# If statement and Html.ActionLink in Razor MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

```
@if (item.hasTypes.Value == true) { 
    Html.ActionLink(item.marketGroupName, "Index", new { id = item.marketGroupID });
}
```

I have this so that if the hasTypes is true, it will create an actionlink. But the above code does not work. It is showing empty in those columns.

Comment: Is it really some value is equal to `true`?

Comment: it is a nullable type, so yes

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I think you forgot an `@` which is used to output:

```
@if (item.hasTypes.Value) { 
    @Html.ActionLink(item.marketGroupName, "Index", new { id = item.marketGroupID });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to actually render the link to the output. Your current code produces a link but doesn't actually do anything with it. Notice the extra `@` below:

```
@if (item.hasTypes.Value == true) { 
    @Html.ActionLink(item.marketGroupName, "Index", new { id = item.marketGroupID });
}
```